# Can I remove battery while my iPhone 4s is still on?

Tags: iphone, battery

I've had this annoying problem with my phone that has happened a few times now. Basically it just totally freezes. My top button is broken, so I can't turn the phone off using that. My assisted touch no longer works, because the screen is pretty much completely frozen.

In the past the only way I've been able to really deal with this problem is by draining the battery and then plugging my phone in to turn it on. This seems to reset it and then it works again. In order to drain my battery I can either ask Siri questions (but unfortunately this also stops working after a while...plus it's annoying as hell), or play music from my iTunes. Playing music from my iTunes does the trick, but it usually takes almost 24 hours to completely drain my battery. Suggestions on draining faster are appreciated...

For today though, I have my first day of work tomorrow and it just went out. I kind of really wanted to have a functional phone for my first day, so I'm a little more desperate. I'm wondering if it would be okay to remove the battery/unplug it and put it back in while my phone is in the frozen state. Obviously the whole phone isn't frozen since it can play music, but the screen and all buttons just don't work. Could this break my phone? Do I have a pretty good chance of nothing bad happening? Thanks lemme knowww.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be possible to perform a reset of the phone by holding the 'home' and 'power' buttons for ten seconds. That should cause the phone to reboot.

If you can't do this (e.g. broken power button), then I don't see why removing the battery would not cause the phone to be shut down.

I don't see why it would cause any lasting damage, at any rate.

Comment: How about getting the power button repaired? ;)

Comment: Yeah I should probably do this, but I can't before work in the morning =p

Comment: Depends what time it is where you are. Here it's nearly 2PM ;)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem a few hours ago. Removing and placing the battery seems to fix the problem. Not sure how long though, but it did helped.